# How does Socialblade index YouTube channels and extract the data they need?

Tags: youtube, indexing

I was wondering how the website, http://socialblade.com indexed YouTube channels and extracted their daily views so the could input them on their website.

I can't provide much more detail because i'm unsure of how their process actually works.

How would i go about doing/creating something similar?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe too late... but you can google "web crawling" or "web scraping". It's a technique to extract data from any web site. There are several tools to help you to do it. Try it.

Bye